# How to rearrange the items of a list and the DOM with MooTools?

Tags: dom, mootools

I'm trying to rearrange the items of a list:

```
<ul>
<li>1 <button><li>
<li>2 <button><li>
<li>3 <button><li>
<li>4 <button><li>
</ul>
```

using MooTools:

```
document.getElements('button').addEvent('click', function() {
    var toSort = new Fx.Sort(this.getParent(),this.getParent().getNext());
    toSort.swap();
    toSort = toSort.rearrangeDOM();
}
```

When I click the button of the first list element y expect:

```
<ul>
<li>2 <button><li>
<li>1 <button><li>
<li>3 <button><li>
<li>4 <button><li>
</ul>
```

but I get:

```
<ul>
<li>2 <button><li>
<li>3 <button><li>
<li>4 <button><li>
<li>1 <button><li>
</ul>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends what the effect is that you want to achieve. what is the purpose of 'button'? move up? move to top? move to bottom?

here's an example of a Fx.Sort use that sends a row up (if not first already)

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ZQhgF/

```
var sort = new Fx.Sort($$("ul li"), {
    transition: Fx.Transitions.linear.easeInOut,
    link: "chain",
    duration: 500,
    mode: "vertical",
    onComplete: function() {
        this.rearrangeDOM();
    }
});

document.getElements('button').addEvent('click', function(e) {
    e.stop();
    var el = this.getParent(), prev = el.getPrevious();
    if (!prev)
        return;
    sort.swap(el, prev);
});
```

which works on this dom:

```
<ul id="sorter">
    <li>1 <button>up</button></li>
    <li>2 <button>up</button></li>
    <li>3 <button>up</button></li>
    <li>4 <button>up</button></li>
</ul>
```

it should give you some ideas. what you could also do is a serialize function that can allow you to set any custom order you want and / or save the order after.